# NSF Grant Status Update

Tags: funding, nsf

Our NSF grant had its status date changed a couple of weeks ago on fastlane, but no change in status (it stays as "pending"). Does anyone know what that means? We submitted the grant in June and it went through a review panel in August.

Comment: That means someone has accessed the grant application but has not processed for the next stage.

Comment: Do you know whether that is a good or a bad sign, given we expect to hear back in Dec/Jan?

Comment: It is definitely a good sign. Soon, it should be processed for the next stage. Good luck :)

Comment: I am actually interested to see if this was indeed a good sign. OP, care to state your experience?